# lift object up in nested object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, transformation

I have a tree object. In its deepest level there is `_metrics` key with value and what I want is to lift `_metrics` up to its parent object.
I am struggling to solve this case as it is the first time I encounter such a case.

**Given Input**

```
const d = {
    "enterprise1": {
        "site1": {
            "area1": {
                "unit1": {
                    "__metrics": {
                        "state_class": "down",
                        "state": "other",
                        "reason": "UNDEFINED",
                        "product": "sovereign",
                        "count": 10
                    }
                },
                "unit2": {
                    "__metrics": {
                        "state_class": "run",
                        "state": "running",
                        "reason": "UNDEFINED",
                        "product": "cola",
                        "count": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The input above will always have `__metrics` object in 4th level which is `"unit"` object.

**Desired output**

```
const d = {
    "enterprise1": {
      "__metrics": {
        "state_class": ["run", "down"],
        "state": ["running", "other"],
        "reason": "UNDEFINED",
        "product": ["cola", "sovereign"],
        "count": 20
      },
        "site1": {
          "__metrics": {
            "state_class": ["run", "down"],
            "state": ["running", "other"],
            "reason": "UNDEFINED",
            "product": ["cola", "sovereign"],
            "count": 20
          },
            "area1": {
               "__metrics": {
                  "state_class": ["run", "down"],
                  "state": ["running", "other"],
                  "reason": "UNDEFINED",
                  "product": ["cola", "sovereign"],
                  "count": 20
                },
                "unit1": {
                    "__metrics": {
                        "state_class": "down",
                        "state": "other",
                        "reason": "UNDEFINED",
                        "product": "sovereign",
                        "count": 10
                    }
                },
                "unit2": {
                    "__metrics": {
                        "state_class": "run",
                        "state": "running",
                        "reason": "UNDEFINED",
                        "product": "cola",
                        "count": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Example cases at [link](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3xyvgxn9j)

Answer (score 1):

I guess javascript doesn't have a library to lift it up the key-value of an object. You could be use to add `__metrics` in each level using for-in loop. The add of `__metrics` is depend how many level deep the object do you have.

The looping would be like this:

```
for (let key_lvl1 in d) {
      //enterprise level
      d[key_lvl1]["__metrics"] = __metrics_both;
      d[key_lvl1] = Object.keys(d[key_lvl1])
        .sort()
        .reduce((obj, key) => {
          obj[key] = d[key_lvl1][key];
          return obj;
        }, {});
      //console.log(d[key_lvl1]);
      for (let key_lvl2 in d[key_lvl1]) {
        //site level
        if (key_lvl2 === "__metrics") continue;
        d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2]["__metrics"] = __metrics_both;   
        d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2] = Object.keys(d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2])
          .sort()
          .reduce((obj, key) => {
            obj[key] = d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key];
            return obj;
          }, {});
        //console.log(d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2]);
        for (let key_lvl3 in d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2]) {
          //area level
          if (key_lvl3 === "__metrics") continue;
          d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3]["__metrics"] = __metrics_both;
          d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3] = Object.keys(
            d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3]
          )
            .sort()
            .reduce((obj, key) => {
              obj[key] = d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3][key];
              return obj;
            }, {});
          //console.log(d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3]);
        }
      }
    }
```

And the overall of the code could be like this:

```js
const d = {
  enterprise1: {
    site1: {
      area1: {
        unit1: {
          __metrics: {
            state_class: "down",
            state: "other",
            reason: "UNDEFINED",
            product: "sovereign",
            count: 10
          }
        },
        unit2: {
          __metrics: {
            state_class: "run",
            state: "running",
            reason: "UNDEFINED",
            product: "cola",
            count: 10
          }
        }
      },
      area2: {
        unit3: {
          __metrics: {
            state_class: "down",
            state: "other",
            reason: "UNDEFINED",
            product: "sovereign",
            count: 10
          }
        },
        unit4: {
          __metrics: {
            state_class: "run",
            state: "running",
            reason: "UNDEFINED",
            product: "cola",
            count: 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

let __metrics_both = {
  state_class: ["run", "down"],
  state: ["running", "other"],
  reason: "UNDEFINED",
  product: ["cola", "sovereign"],
  count: 20
};

for (let key_lvl1 in d) {
  //enterprise level
  d[key_lvl1]["__metrics"] = __metrics_both;
  d[key_lvl1] = Object.keys(d[key_lvl1])
    .sort()
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = d[key_lvl1][key];
      return obj;
    }, {});
  //console.log(d[key_lvl1]);
  for (let key_lvl2 in d[key_lvl1]) {
    //site level
    if (key_lvl2 === "__metrics") continue;
    d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2]["__metrics"] = __metrics_both;   
    d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2] = Object.keys(d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2])
      .sort()
      .reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key];
        return obj;
      }, {});
    //console.log(d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2]);
    for (let key_lvl3 in d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2]) {
      //area level
      if (key_lvl3 === "__metrics") continue;
      d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3]["__metrics"] = __metrics_both;
      d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3] = Object.keys(
        d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3]
      )
        .sort()
        .reduce((obj, key) => {
          obj[key] = d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3][key];
          return obj;
        }, {});
      //console.log(d[key_lvl1][key_lvl2][key_lvl3]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(d);
```

maybe it's not the best practice, but it's almost what you'd expect. it would be better if `__metrics` were added at each level when the data objects were added to the table. Hope you like it :)